# Problems with numpy in PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, numpy, module, pycharm

I can't seem to install *numpy* to PyCharm.

I started with an up-to-date, fresh install of Python 2.7.8 and PyCharm 3.4.1.

Then I installed *winpython* in PyCharm to get the *numpy* and *scipy* packages using

File > Default Settings > Project Interpreter > selected Python 2.7.7 > installing *pip* and *setuptools* > installing *winpython*...

After installing these, I went to run a simple code using *numpy* and continue to get an error of "**no module named *numpy***". My professor did the exact same thing and his works fine (both using Windows 7).

Answer (score 4):

Go to the [Winpython website](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/), download the version according to your needs and install it locally. Then open PyCharm and add a new python interpreter giving the path of where you installed Winpython to (the python-... subirectory).

Winpython is a Python *distribution*, it provides a python environment with packages like Numpy or Scipy precompiled and preinstalled. It's not a package itself (there is one, but this is not the entire distribution!).