# Using WinPython as Interpreter for PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

sorry for a simple question! I want to use WinPython (recently installed) as a interpreter for PyCharm Community Edition but am getting an error

> "The selected file is not a valid home for Python SDK"

(see image)

Does anybody have any idea of what the issue may be? Do I have to do any other steps (with the path, etc.)?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to select the folder where a `python.exe` (and possibly `pythonw.exe`) exists, which looks like maybe the `python-3.4.4.amd64` folder

And, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948973/2308683)

> open PyCharm and add a new python interpreter giving the path of where you installed Winpython to (the python-... subirectory).