# How to select winpython interpreter for Visual Studio 2017 community edition?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I want to use winpython interpreter for Visual Studio 2017 community edition. I found settings for another IDE here: [Using WinPython as Interpreter for PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386252/using-winpython-as-interpreter-for-pycharm). Where can I find similar settings for VS 2017 community edition?

Comment: From the information is [this document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2017/03/07/python-support-in-vs2017/) it sound like it would happen when you install VS, if it's a version of Python it recognizes/detects. There's may be ways of doing it after-the-fact...and you might have better luck asking about it at  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com.

Answer (score 1):

(finally my first post after so long following. It's a shame, because it's maybe not the best answer, but it's late here)

You have to add your WinPython as a custom python enviroment.

Following steps:

1. Open VS an look for Tools > Python > Python Enviroments and then hit "add custom..."
2. There are several fields to be filled, which are nearly self explained (Path of Interpreter, window-interpreter etc.). I think, if you enter the Interpreter-Path, you can hit the button "auto-fill" on the right side an VS will try to look for the other fields automatically.

That's it. But the more interesting question is "Does Intellisense recognizes the packages in WinPython like scipy?"

Yes. But Intellisense needs a first date with the packages. Otherwise you won't cross the doorstep.

1. Open Tools > Python > Python Enviroments
2. Click on your Custom Python environment (WinPython, I still guess) and then click the field, where "configure" is listed an look for the Option "Intellisense". Then VS will look vor all modules. Be patient, at my machine it took some time.
3. After recognizing all modules (no red ! sign anymore, a blue check), you can hit the new appearing button above "Update Database". This will take less time.
4. In my case (a few minutes ago) I had to restart VS. When I hit numpy.p either in editor or interactive console, there appears auto-complete with every info you wish to have (in a pythonic, not a general way).

good night!

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments
- [Visual Studio How to add Python module to Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605416/visual-studio-how-to-add-python-module-to-intellisense)