# Puzzled by PyCharm, WinPython and IPython

Tags: python, pycharm

Im a newby to Python, so please forgive me if my question is easily answered.

I have many years of C++ programming, but am now attracted by Python because of the simple programming style and the vast amount of boilerplate solutions.

Now comes my problem: I'm working under Windows and there one has PyCharm, from which WinPython can be used (which is attractive because it contains almost all packages for scientific computing); on the other hand WinPython also contains different Python interpreters like e.g. IPython.

What I could not find online, is a comprehensive explanation of how to e.g. configure PyCharm to use WinPython and there IPython.
Could also be that I completely misunderstand the concepts of PyCharm and WinPython so that I only can use IPython directly and not indirectly via the PyCharm&WinPython access layers.

If anyone could shed some light on those mysteries, it would a great help to me.

Edit:
I know how to use WinPython from PyCharm; my question is related to the interplay between three "parties" PyCharm, WinPython and e.g. IPython that is contained in WinPython.
I have of course checked the online documentations for the three parts separately but couldn't find any information about whether the PyCharm uses WinPython with the Python interpreter that is set in WinPython or, whether e.g. IPython can not be used via WinPython when using PyCharm.
What I am looking for is a handson installation/configuration tutorial for all three in combination and not something that is sleeping behind a thicket of criss-cross references or a wall of abstract hinting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using WinPython as Interpreter for PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386252/using-winpython-as-interpreter-for-pycharm)

Comment: Have you checked out the PyCharm doocs? (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scientific-tools.html)